# space between rows in table html

Tags: html

How to add space to the specific row in HTML.

```html
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
           1
        </td>
     <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
    <tr>

</table>
```

I want to add space between 2 and 3 only.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your second `<tr>`:

`style="height: 20px; vertical-align: top;"`

So it becomes:

    
      2

As a side note, I would recommend you to take a look at what [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) is.

Comment: @user3398632 can you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: @user3398632 change margin-bottom to height.

Answer (score -1):

the  tag has the height attribute, try something like this

```
<tr height="20">
```

Comment: ugh... you probably dont see any changes because I think 20 is the size of a regular row, try changing the value to 50 and you will see the difference, change the number to whatever you think it looks good.